# How to fix cascading branches rebasing mess

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

We have a workflow where **only one** team member works on several feature branches. Work is such that each next branch is dependent on previous one he did.  The default branch is `develop`.

Lets say this scenario:

1. He creates `featureA` branch, does the work, pushes the branch, and creates a PR on GitHub
2. He creates `featureB` branch (based on `featureA` one), does the work and PRs it
3. He creates `featureC` branch, (based on `featureB`) does the work and PRs it
4. he creates `featureD` branch, (based on `featureC`) does the work and PRs it

None of the PRs are merged yet.

Now, project manager steps in and starts merging. Merge go this way:

1. Project manager merges `featureA` into develop
2. Developer on his side does:

   ```
   git checkout develop
   git fetch origin
   git rebase origin/develop
   git checkout featureB
   git rebase origin/develop
   git push origin featureB
   ```

At this point of time we get error:

```
machine /c/Work/ (featureB)
$ git push origin featureB
To https://github.com/x.git
 ! [rejected]        featureB -> featureB (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/x.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Why does this happen?

We thought that rebasing `featureB` on `origin/develop` (which now after merge contains `featureA`) would make `featureB` ready for push. but obviously we see something wrong.

Comment: "PRs it" <-- against what? Are you maybe confusing "Push it" with "make a pull request" and with "merge a branch"? These are different things...

Comment: against develop branch. in text: "develop is a default branch"

Comment: i don't think i'm confusing push, PR and merge. developer pushes and creates pull request (PRs), manager merges it.

Comment: I've put in some explanations in post UPDATEs. hope that makes a bit more clear?

Comment: Is there any real reason to rebase these branches?  Alternatively, I would also imagine that a conflict in one of these branches would indicate a conflict regardless of merge or rebase.

Comment: well, i don't know the answer to that question. we thought there is but obviously, we are not sure. that's one of the reasons asking a question here: what are we doing wrong. PS. there are no conflicts in branches.

Comment: Why are you rebasing instead of merging? Based on the question, this does not seem like a case for rebase, it seems like a case for merge.

Comment: i am not sure why. it seemed to us like a way to do it. obviously, we didn't know better. could you please post your answer with solution how would you cover this workflow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to explain what happened is to look at your repo's history.  Here is what (an abridged version of) your history looked like pre-merge:

```
*--*--*--* [develop, origin/develop]
          \
           *--*--* [featureA, origin/featureA]
                  \
                   A--B--C [featureB, origin/featureB]
```

And post-merge:

```
*--*--*--*---------* [develop, origin/develop]
          \       /
           *--*--*
                  \
                   A--B--C [featureB, origin/featureB]
```

Then you rebased `featureB` onto `develop`:

```
*--*--*--*---------* [develop, origin/develop]
          \       / \
           *--*--*   A'--B'--C' [featureB]
                  \
                   A--B--C [origin/featureB]
```

Here, `A'`, `B'`, and `C'`, contain the same changes as `A`, `B`, and `C`, respectively, *but they are not the same commits*, because `A'` has a different parent commit.

Thus, after each rebase, you must force-push the rebased branch:

```
git push --force-with-lease origin featureB
```

(The `--force-with-lease` ensures that no new commits have been pushed since you last fetched.  While it might not be strictly needed here, it's good to get in the habit of using that over `--force`.)

As seen in my last graph, any time a branch (such as `featureB`) and its remote-tracking branch (such as `origin/featureB`) have diverged, you must force-push.  Thus, you will need to do that any time you have rebased a branch that has already been pushed to the remote.

Comment: wow! now when i run gitk i see that is exactly what happens. let me just ask you then, is --force-with-lease just a fix for this situation but there is better git way to cover for our workflow or is it something we should normally use? in other words, would you normaly cover our workflow this or some other way?

Comment: This gives a real insight to what happened. thanks a ton!